Issues with launching the MyFiles App in a specified folder
i am trying to open the mobile app called "My Files" in a specified folder but can't seem to get it to work, it may be because i am using the wrong myfiles activity but i haven't found a document detailing which activity to use to open the app and go to the specified folder.
Currently the app opens to the main menu and so i was wondering if someone knew if it is possible and how to do it.
The code shown below is used to get the myfiles app launched but as already said, can't seem to get it to go to the directory i want it to
The button used to open the My Files app
Button(
            onClick = {
                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
                intent.setComponent(ComponentName("com.sec.android.app.myfiles", "com.sec.android.app.myfiles.external.ui.MainActivity"))
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

                // path to the folder: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MAIN_DIRECTORY_NAME
                val picturesFolder = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), MAIN_DIRECTORY_NAME)
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ORIGINATING_URI, Uri.fromFile(picturesFolder))

                context.startActivity(intent)
            }
) {
    Text(text = "Open")
}

Where it sends me
My Files app, the location it sends me
If more detail is needed, i would be happy to provide more
And thanks in advance

Are you aware that com.sec.android.app.myfiles is a Samsung specific app? Therefore your code will only work on Samsung devices (once it works as expected).

Yes I am aware, as this app is intended for internal use only, and only Samsung phones are used, I came to the conclusion to just use the preinstalled folder app instead of needing to install a new file manager app or creating my own. If what I want to achieve is not possible due to possible restrictions from the My Files app itself, I'd consider using a different file manager. Still, thank you for pointing that out

How have you determined that MyFiles is supposed to honor that particular Intent extra for that particular Intent action?

You should better download the myfiles APK and use Jadx-Gui or a similar tool to decompile it and see what action and extra data it expects.
